# Working with slug field in Django

Tags: python, django

I made a slug field and I made migrations. My slug field is called slug and it is visible in in the site administration, but it doesn't work properly.

My browser tells me:

TypeError at /None/
    detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data_published = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    large_description = models.TextField(max_length=20000)

    def __str__(self):             
    return self.title

    def save(self):
    if not self.id:
        self.s = slugify(self.q)

    super(test, self).save()

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.datum_objave >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', 'books.views.index', name='index'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$', 'books.views.detail', name='detail'), 
]   

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

index.html

```
{% extends "master.html"  %} 
{% block h1 %} 
<div class="box first">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        {% for question  in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="{{ question.slug }} " i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a>
                    <h4>{{ question.title }} </h4>
                    <p>{{ question.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Index {% endblock %}
```

admin.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin

 from .models import Question


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
question_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, book_title):
    question = Question.objects.get(title=book_title)
    return render(request, 'books/detail.html', {'question': question})`
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "master2.html"  %}
{% block h1 %} 
<div class="center">
    <h4>{{question.title}} </h4>
    <p>{{question.large_description}}</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Detail {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your detail view, since that's the one with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of your urls.py, `(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)`, means that there is a view that accepts a parameter named slug and if Django is unable to find that view, it will complain. So your view should probably be something like this:

```
def detail(request, slug):
    question = Question.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'papers/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

**UPDATE**
It's also a good idea not to create your urls manually in your templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' question.slug %}">{{ question.naslov }}</a>
```

Comment: Now it says Question matching query does not exist.                                  I'm sorry I'm new at this

Comment: Then there is no question in the database with the slug you provided in your url.

Comment: Could you please help me, what should I do next?

Comment: There is nothing wrong now. Your questions are displayed in index and when a question is clicked it's details are shown in details. I updated the answer with another note.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I don't now do we understand each each other. When I click on a detail on my index page the browser tells me: DoesNotExist at /None/
Question matching query does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77643/discussion-between-nima-and-kemo146).

Comment: Your slug field has null=True. It's probably not you want because all of the books should have a slug.  
Did you change your question link to what I wrote in the updated answer?